# Как не отображать ничего при null?

Tags: wpf

У меня есть коллекция с моделью:

```
private ObservableCollection<AccessPointTransmissionModel> AccessPointTransmission { get; } = new();

public class AccessPointTransmissionModel
{    
    public string? OnlyForTestType { get; set; }
    public string? OnlyForTestDelivery { get; set; }
}
```

Когда приходит событие под названием "event", я добавляю все в OnlyForTestType, в другом случае - в OnlyForTestDelivery
Т.е в каком-то случае, одно из полей, будет null.

Дальше мне необходимо все это вывести и я делаю это так:

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding AccessPointTransmission}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">                                                 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                                                       
        <DataTemplate>                                                                                                           
            <Grid>                                                                                                               
                <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                 
                    <Image Source="../Assets/arrow_left_green.png" Height="20"/>                                                 
                    <TextBlock                                                                                                   
                        Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AccessPointBackgroundConverter}}"                         
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding OnlyForTestDelivery}"/>                                        
                </StackPanel>                                                                                                    
                <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                 
                    <Image Source="../Assets/arrow_right_blue.png" Height="20"/>                                                 
                    <TextBlock                                                                                                   
                        Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AccessPointBackgroundConverter}}"                         
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding OnlyForTestType}"/>                                            
                </StackPanel>                                                                                                    
            </Grid>                                                                                                              
        </DataTemplate>                                                                                                          
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                                                      
</ListBox>
```

Но столкнулся я с большой проблемой - данные дублируются. В коллекции 2 элемента, а рисуется 4 стрелки, с двумя пустыми полями:

```
<- command
<-
->
-> event
```

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Добавляю объекты вот так:
..

```
if ( context.Delivery.Header.Name.In( accessPointGenericEvents ) )
{
    AccessPointTransmission.Insert( 0, new AccessPointTransmissionModel{Type = type} );
}
else
{
    AccessPointTransmission.Insert( 0, new AccessPointTransmissionModel {Delivery = delivery});
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы вообще добавляете объект, если он пустой? Сделайте проверку перед добавление в коллекцию, если там нужные свойства null, то пропускать, иначе добавить. Это ведь не проблема разметки (UI).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я обновил вопрос. Мне кажется, я нормально добавляю

Comment: Да, только где проверка на пустоту? Если у вас 2 пустых объекта приходит, то как я и писал выше, сделайте проверку "Если ... равен null то return, иначе выполнить код добавления"

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в модель добавляется либо одно, либо другое. 2 пустых не может быть, я не понимаю, что я могу тут на пустоту проверять